# Running multiple sites at once with WebMatrix 2 without opening it up multiple times

Tags: iis, web, webmatrix, iis-express

Since I have began using WebMatrix, I have developed many of my organization's web-interface, intranet sites. I am now up to four, almost five sites running all at once for users to connect to, and I am afraid that opening up that many instances of the entire WebMatrix app may result in a waste of the server's resources.

I have been scouring the Internet for a reference to how to run multiple sites with WebMatrix.  I haven't exactly come up empty handed, however, I haven't found a solution I like either (even though sources suggest this is entirely possible).

Even though I do know how to run multiple sites at once with WebMatrix (simply open up another instance of WebMatrix) my first question is:  Isn't this more resource intensive (for the server using iis-express) then it needs to be?  Is it beneficial to turn these sites on via command line over simply opening up several instances of WebMatrix?

Last Question:  I found this article here...:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1677533.aspx/1

...where Mike Brind suggests that this can be done by using command-line to browse to the correct iis-express directory (for me: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express) and using the command:

```
iisexpress /site:EmptySite1
```

Where EmptySite1 is the name of the site desired to be ran.

I get this error when trying this:

```
Command Line switches must be preceded by a '-' or '/'...
```

Any clue how I can run multiple sites at once from command-line, or if I even need to?
(Sorry I am in no way a command line guru, as I'm sure you can, by now, tell)
I am running Windows Server 2008 R2, if that matters.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running full blown Windows Server 2008, install regular IIS.  It can run multiple websites all at once without having any special command lines.  Since it runs as a service, IIS will automatically restart if and when the server is rebooted.  The downside is that IIS is a bit more complicated to configure than IIS express.

Comment: And... Therein lies the problem.  I think it would be easier to simply create a batch file and run it as a part of the server's startup.

Comment: I can tell you what I did.  I asked for a consultant's help to get it deployed from IIS express to IIS.  He was knowledgeable about IIS.  He and I spent about a total of 2 hours on it.  At the end, he said I owed him nothing since it was a learning exercise for him since he did not know WebMatrix.  The hardest issue was that about half a dozen files needed to be added to the BIN folder to support webMatrix.